# bufferedimage image.getRGB and image.setRGB not refer to same pixel

Tags: java

i have problem with setRGB() method. After get int color=getRGB(x,y) then setRGB(x,y,color) the image had changed.

```
File file=new File(fileName);
image = ImageIO.read(file);
            int width=image.getWidth();
            int high=image.getHeight();
            for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < width; xPixel++)
            {
                for (int yPixel=0; yPixel<high; yPixel++)
                {
                    int color = image.getRGB(xPixel, xPixel);                
                    image.setRGB(xPixel, yPixel, color);                                    
                }
            }
```

Then i write the image to a bmp file. the new image is not same with old image.
What is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the getRGB- Function with xPixel and xPixel.
and the set function with xPixel and yPixel as arguments.

I think your code must be

```
 int color = image.getRGB(xPixel, yPixel);                
 image.setRGB(xPixel, yPixel, color);
```

Comment: No it is not the same. The second parameter of the get method is `xPixel` and on my code the second parameter is `yPixel` the difference is the `x` in your code and the `y` in my code.